# How can PCA eigenvectors be used to classify images?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, pattern-recognition

I have been asked to classify a set of images (which are in two class) using 10 component eigenvectors.

I've got no problem in generating eigenvectors of images, However I have no idea how eigenvectors can be used to classify images.

As I know PCA is a way to reduce dimension, so how eigenvectors created using PCA can be used to classify images?

Comment: The Principal Components you created are orthogonal, meaning they are uncorrelated.  This is very helpful for classification, as often high multicollinearity skews results.  Once you have these orthogonal components you may use a prediction method (regression) to 'classify' your inputs, using PCs as new covariates.

Comment: @E.Trauger Thank you, your comment made it less blurry to me, however I still can't figure out which part these 10 generated eigenvectors will be playing in learning or prediction process...

Comment: You use the eigenvectors that capture a large portion of the variance (~95% or so) as the new covariates in a regression.  You can decompose the PCs down to original covariates if you would like, but it is easier to use the loadings of the PCs and the weights of the PCs (given by the eigenvalues) to run a regression directly.  Then you can "predict" based on the PC coefficients.  Check out Principal Components Regression (PCR) for help with this.  R has `pls` package with `pcr()` function for this exact purpose.

Comment: [Here](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/05/feature-extraction-using-pca/) is an overview of what you are looking to do, on a conceptual level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you got eigenvectors, they provide you with coefficients to convert the input data into a 10-dimensional vector. So you get a vector for each sample. Rn the logistic regression using these vectors as inputs. The regression is your classifier.

Comment: Thank you... I some how figure it out by chance (reading some documents and playing with my codes)...

Answer (score 2):

I know I have am in the comments, but I actually found this picture pretty useful.  It shows what the PCA is doing (drawing axes, projecting, separating the pictures), albeit in 2-dimensions (2 PCs being used).  This 2-dimension process is extended for $n$-dimensions, based on the number $n$ of Principal Components you choose to use.

Here you can see (in the second case) drawing a new axis based on the "features" allows you separate the images well.  You ran PCA to get the 2-D plot, and now you can use the position of images on the "feature" graph to predict the image classification, based on its position on the corresponding line.

The image also shows the downfall of this method's assumptions (in the top sequence).  You are assuming most discriminant information can be captured by the largest variances (first two PCs, or "features," in this case).  In some cases, like in the first case, the most discriminant information is *not* held in the direction of the largest variance.  You do not need to worry about this case, most likely, for your application, but it is good to note for future cases or cases where discriminant information is held in the directions of smallest variance.

[image: PCA]

Comment: Thanks... I have to read the whole article I guess +1 ;)